# How to debug a stored procedure without using debugger

Tags: sql-server

How can I debug a stored procedure in SQL Server without using debugger?

There are too many select statements and find out which select statement causes an error.

I don't have permissions to execute stored procedure and debugger.

Comment: Can you change it?

Comment: You comment out all statements in the procedure except the first. Execute. Verify no errors, Then uncomment the next. Repeat. You can put print statements in the body to "see" progress.